# Scan file from computer 1 through computer 2 and get back the result?

Tags: linux, shell

I have antivirus which run through terminal like i have to type

```
malice scan filename.txt > results.MD
```

And it store result it `result.MM` I need to scan my file which is present in my computer 1 . How should I scan my computer 1 file from computer 2 and get back the result?

OS : Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write and run shell script on computer 2:

1. SSH connect (via sshpass -p)
2. SCP transfer file to computer 1

For example (script.sh content):

```
$sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip_address_second_computer
$scp result.MD user@ip_address_first_computer:/home/path_to_file/result.MD
```

Also you can add `malice scan filename.txt > results.MD` between `scp` transfer for connect->scan->transfer scenario.

Comment: it copy file from computer 2 to computer 1. After the **filename.txt** copy in to computer 1 i need to scan that file and then send back the result.md file to computer 2.

Comment: ssh connect to connect computer 2 -> scp send to computer 1 -> scan on computer 1 -> send to computer 2